# Factorization of an irreducible polynomial in the field extension it defines

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, fields

In field theory, the following fact is used in the construction of splitting fields: *Given a field $F$ and an irreducible polynomial $f \in F[x]$, the quotient $F[\alpha]/(f(\alpha))$ is a field extension of $F$ which contains a root of $f$ (namely the congruence class of $\alpha$).*

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $\lambda_{1} + \dotsb + \lambda_{k} = n$ be a partition of $n$. Does there exist a field $F$ and an irreducible polynomial $f \in F[x]$ of degree $\deg f = n+1$ such that, if we define $K := F[\alpha]/(f(\alpha))$, the factorization of $f$ in $K[x]$ is of the form $f = (x-\alpha) \cdot f_{1} \dotsb f_{k}$ where each $f_{i} \in K[x]$ is irreducible and $\deg f_{i} = \lambda_{i}$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let us show that for the partition $2+1+1=4$, there is no such $f$.

If $f$ were inseparable, then over $K$ it would factor as a constant times $(x-\alpha)^5$.  If $f$ were separable, its Galois group $G$ would be a transitive subgroup of $S_5$ containing a transposition, so $G=S_5$, but then the stabilizer of a point would act transitively on the other four points, so $f$ would factor over $K$ into $x-\alpha$ and an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$.

Comment: You could replace $S_5$ by $S_p$ for each prime $p\geq 5$ and the partition having one $2$ and all other terms equal to $1$.

Comment: For $n \geq 7$ there is different partition of $n$ that can't occur for *separable* $f$. By Bertrand's postulate, there is a prime $p$ s.t. $(n+1)/2 < p \leq n-2$. Use the partition $p + 2 + 1 + \cdots + 1 = n$; it has $k := n-p$ terms. The Galois group $G$ of $f$ over $F$ has a permutation $\sigma$ of the $n+1$ roots of type $(p,2,1,\ldots,1)$. Then $\sigma^2$ is a $p$-cycle on the roots and $\sigma^p$ is a $2$-cycle on the roots. A transitive subgroup of $S_{n+1}$ having a $2$-cycle and $p$-cycle is $S_{n+1}$, so Bjorn's argument shows $f/(x-\alpha)$ is irred. of degree $n$: contradiction.